# Can't extend volume

Tags: windows-server-2008, diskmanagement

Can't extend volume under Server 2008 SP2. Please help?

Disk 1 has 512 GB taken, but 512 GB unallocated. The extend volume wizard doesn't allow me to click Next with additional space.

[image: Disk Management]

[image: Extend Volume Wizard]

Comment: Does it work with a smaller number?

Comment: Yes it does. 524287. I've never come across that before. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try making the volume just a tad smaller than the maximum disk size. Note the discrepancy between highlighted value and maximum size. See if that works to restore the grayed-out menu.

Answer (score 1):

It says 524288 is free and you are trying to take more than the free space, ie 524289.

You have the right situation here,

- your disk is basic,
- it is not a system partition
- it is healthy
- it is NTFS

just this tidbit.